# Dynamically theming Status Bar according to app's Action Bar?

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, xposed-framework, material-design, tinted-status-bar

I have no idea whether this question is on-topic or off-topic here, because it is related to problems with an Xposed Module. Moderators, please tell me if this is off-topic or not.

I'm running on an AOSP-based Jelly Bean 4.2.2 ROM, rooted and having Xposed Framework. I have GravityBox, Tinted Status Bar, XBlast Tools, etc. and many other modules installed on my device, including the Monster UI module, which themes my device framework to make all apps look like having Material design (checkboxes, progress bars, ripple effects, etc).

I have applied a system-wide Material design colour scheme, including dialog boxes and action bars for apps which were using Holo themes, all through Monster UI. On top of that, to get the full Lollipop effect, I have used the Tinted Status Bar module to tint the Status Bar according to the app's Action Bar colour. When I launch any app's main activity, it works fine, and tints the Status Bar accordingly. But, when I switch back and forth across various activities in the app, the Status Bar gets tinted White, and sometimes that makes the Action Bar turn white too, rendering the text/icons which both were supposed to display, invisible.

How do I fix this ?

Note : All modules work perfectly, and none are conflicting with each other. I checked MANY times for any such conflicts, but there were none. Disabling other modules too didn't work out.

Comment: Could this be a combat between two or more theming apps?

Answer (score 1):

Look's like a bug in Tinted Status Bar module, because other than this everything works fine.

So, give your feedback to module developer [MohammadAG - XDA Profile](http://forum.xda-developers.com/member.php?u=2011359)
or [Tinted Status Bar thread - XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/xposed/modules/mod-tinted-status-bar-t2457265)